# How to migrate a database along with a java application

Tags: java, database

i have a java application which uses netbeans' Java DB/Derby.
i have "clean and build" the project creating a jar file, but it'll only run if i explicitly run netbeans and start database there.
how can i set the DB to start up automatically along with jar file and also, that if i sent that jar file to someone else, that database goes along with that(i have read it's possible to do that with derby. not sure though)
any help is appreciated

Comment: Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.3.3.0/devguide/tdevdvlp38381.html). Or, for more detail, [this](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/embedded_intro.html).

Answer (score 0):

you need to include sql resources and create the database with these on running the project for the first time . This is a cumbersome process and platform depending ...

there are solutions available that allow for creation of a dictionary in a java project , hence making this platform independ. SAP NetWeaver has this  but I'm sure there are others ..

Comment: i don't know how to do that.
any tutorial or web resource on how it can be done. ?